# How to use .delay() and .timer() in RXJava2 inside a chain?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I would like to learn how to use RX's `.delay()` and `.timer()`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    showTime()
        .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .andThen(showTime())
        .subscribe()
}

private fun showTime(): Completable =
    Completable.fromAction {
        val time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()
        println(time)
    }
```

I would like the above code to print time twice with 2 seconds in between. However, it only prints once.

I have also tried to use `.timer()` and did't work either.

```
    showTime()
        .andThen(Completable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .andThen(showTime())
        .subscribe()
```

Can someone show me the right way of print time twice with 2 seconds in between using `.delay()` and `.timer()` in RX?

Comment: Your main method quits too early. Add `sleep(3000)` after the subscribe call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Observable.interval` - it's emits items with passed delay. In the example below, it ticks every 2 seconds (`interval`) for 2 times (`take(2)`) and stops.

```
Observable
        .interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .take(2)
        .subscribe();
```

If you still want to use `timer` and `delay` only, you can do something like this.
I actually don't think you should use `delay` here, since when you call second `timer` after first one it still delays its emition by given time.

```
fun start() {
    tick().andThen(tick())

}

fun tick(): Completable {
    return Completable
            .timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe {
                val time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()).atZone(
                        ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime()
                println(time)
            }
}
```